# Emptying input field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular seems to have a different behavior when a user enters and then clears text in an input field depending if this field is required or not.

Take a look at this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input). By default the model is `user = {"name":"guest","last":"visitor"}`. When clearing both fields the model becomes `user = {"last":""}` whereas I would have expected `user = {}`.

Why is this the case? And, is there a way to get the same behavior for both fields without making them both (not) required?

Update:

I used a workaround with watch in the end:

```
$scope.$watch('user',function(newValue) {
  for (var prop in newValue) {
    if (newValue.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      if (newValue[prop] !== undefined && newValue[prop] == "")
        newValue[prop] = undefined;
    }
  }
}, true);
```

Most likely the last if-condition could be written more efficiently, but at least it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Just for the sake that if a field is required in input, its value should not go something like empty or null.

Comment: Then how to get the same behavior for the non-required input fields?

Comment: you can trigger a function on field emptying which actually deletes the specified field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there's an error in validation, [the model is set to `undefined`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d077966ff1ac18262f4615ff1a533db24d4432a7/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L539-L553) hence the disappearing `name` key (which is validated with `required`).

It's a known bug in Angular that an empty field with `ng-minlength` does not get invalidated correctly. If you set the value to `a` (which is still 2 letters short of minimum 3) you'll notice both keys disappear correctly.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7277

Comment: I have implemented a work-around with a watch function which simply tests if the field is "" and, if so, sets it to undefined. Seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This situation creates because "User Name:" field has `required` validation ,so when you clear "User Name:" field. "User Name:" field doesn't pass the `required` validation. As a result, the model becomes `user = {"last":""}`

On the other hand, "Last name:" has `ng-minlength="3"` and `ng-maxlength="10"` validation so, after clear "Last Name:" field when you enter 1 or 2 character on "Last Name:" field. It doesn't pass the `minlength` validation so, the model becomes `user = {}`

so if any `validation` fails like "User Name:" field, it vanish from the model and the model becomes `user = {"last":""}`

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Chris is rightly expecting that an empty string would still be resulting in `user = {}`, but it's not, due to a bug in Angular.

Comment: No. as i explained, if the field don't pass validation. It vanish from the model.

Comment: Except, that as the example indicates, when a `minlength` input is empty it should not be passing validation, however it does.

Answer (score 0):

If the result would be `user = {}`, then it would mean that Angular would have to actually `delete` that property entirely, by calling user.delete('last'), which is something it can not do. It does not know anything about `person` object. It only got reference to the `person.last` property

Comment: That's actually what Angular does. When a model is invalidated, the model value is set to `undefined` while the view value retains whatever you're typing.

Comment: See the logic here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d077966ff1ac18262f4615ff1a533db24d4432a7/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L539-L553